# Is it possible to have protected routes in Remix.run, so the browser doesn't get the protected source code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, remix.run

Is it possible to have protected routes in the Remix.run React framework, so that only admin users get the protected components, while regular users don't get the protected components at all as part of the JS bundle sent to the browser?

Also, this may require a form of code splitting on the front end side. Is code splitting supported in Remix.run?

Comment: I'd imagine if it was possible it would for sure certainly involve splitting the code up so specific chunks are only requested under specific conditions. I think this question is then more about whether or not code splitting works or not in remix.run, and not much to do with `react-router` and the like.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this is a code snippet from a [sample app I wrote](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/supabase-remix-auth/blob/main/app/routes/index.jsx), this is the home page and can only be accessed if the user is authenticated.

the `` redirect(`/login?${searchParams}`) `` will redirect if the user isn't authenticated

```
// Loaders provide data to components and are only ever called on the server, so
// you can connect to a database or run any server side code you want right next
// to the component that renders it.
// https://remix.run/api/conventions#loader
export let loader = async ({ request }) => {
  const redirectTo = new URL(request.url).pathname;

  let session = await getSession(request.headers.get("Cookie"));

  // if there is no access token in the header then
  // the user is not authenticated, go to login
  if (!session.has("access_token")) {
    let searchParams = new URLSearchParams([["redirectTo", redirectTo]]);
    throw redirect(`/login?${searchParams}`);
  } else {
    // otherwise execute the query for the page, but first get token
    const { user, error: sessionErr } = await supabaseClient.auth.api.getUser(
      session.get("access_token")
    );

    // if no error then get then set authenticated session
    // to match the user associated with the access_token
    if (!sessionErr) {
      // activate the session with the auth_token
      supabaseClient.auth.setAuth(session.get("access_token"));

      // now query the data you want from supabase
      const { data: chargers, error } = await supabaseClient
        .from("chargers")
        .select("*");

      // return data and any potential errors alont with user
      return { chargers, error, user };
    } else {
      return { error: sessionErr };
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You can protect routes by authorizing the user inside the loader of the Route, there you could decide to redirect it somewhere else or send a flag as part of the loader data so the UI can hide/show components based on it.

For the code splitting, Remix does it at the route level, but it doesn't support server-side code-splitting out of the box, you may be able to support it with react-loadable.

Answer (score 3):

I hope it has, but not. Below is the official answer.

https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/pages/faq#how-can-i-have-a-parent-route-loader-validate-the-user-and-protect-all-child-routes

> You can't . During a client side transition, to make your app as speedy as possible, Remix will call all of your loaders in parallel, in separate fetch requests. Each one of them needs to have its own authentication check.

> This is probably not different than what you were doing before Remix, it might just be more obvious now. Outside of Remix, when you make multiple fetches to your "API Routes", each of those endpoints needs to validate the user session. In other words, Remix route loaders are their own "API Route" and must be treated as such.

> We recommend you create a function that validates the user session that can be added to any routes that require it.